# viewDidLoad vs appDelegate methods

Tags: objective-c

I persist to be a little confused about when to put something in a viewController and when to put it inside an AppDelegate, and if it is ok to reference viewController methods from the AppDelegate (i know you *can* but that doesn't mean it is *encouraged*).

Really, I wouldn't be confused if it weren't for all this multi-tasking stuff that seems to complicate the concepts for me. First, if anyone knows of a good, thorough and easy to read overview of how to deal with multitasking, I'd love to know.

Here's the deal: there are things I need my app to do when it loads, whether loading fresh or loading from the background. Stuff like perform a network reachability test, setup the interface based on data received from the internet, and this or that.

One of my main questions relates to how the viewcontroller's view interacts with background states. If the app resumes from the background and the view is immediately present without loading, then I assume it is still in memory and I have verified that viewDidLoad was not called with a basic NSLog. **So, is it safe to say that any and all objects retained by my viewcontroller (like the data models and all subviews) are thus still in memory?** If not, what's the best practice discovering which objects need to be re-loaded, what are still there, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's safe to assume that [the standard memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) apply, even in a multi-tasking environment. That means that your controller, and anything you've got a reference to in your controller should still be valid until either:

1. You explicitly deallocate your controller/objects
2. Your app terminates

It seems like your assumption is that the system is going to mess with your objects behind your back, which (I hope) can't happen. Those methods are there in the app delegate in case you want to explicitly do anything when those particular events occur.

Regarding the `viewDidLoad` question, you could implement `viewDidUnload` or check the `isViewLoaded` method to make sure your view wasn't unloaded due to a low memory condition or otherwise. More on this in the [UIViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this problem is with lazily-loaded properties. In your .h file:

```
@interface YourViewController : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *exampleObject;
@end
```

And in your .m file:

```
@implementation YourViewController

@synthesize exampleObject = _exampleObject;

- (NSArray *)exampleObject {
    // reload only if necessary
    if (!_exampleObject) {
        _exampleObject = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        // do whatever other setup you need to
    }
    return _exampleObject;
}

@end
```

Comment: the underscore `_` in the `@synthesize` means that the property is to be created right away following the `exampleObject` method?

Comment: No. If you just do `@synthesize exampleObject`, the underlying instance variable for the `exampleObject` property will be named `exampleProperty`. `@synthesize exampleObject = _exampleObject` instructs the compiler to name the instance variable `_exampleObject` (avoids confusion between references to the property and the instance variable).

Comment: The method I defined is a custom getter for the property that instantiates the array on demand (i.e., if it has not yet been instantiated).

Comment: your custom getter would only get called if you did *not* use dot notation on the ivar and instead performed `[self exampleObject]`, right?

Comment: No, the custom getter overrides the default one and gets called whether you do `self.exampleObject` or `[self exampleObject]`.

Comment: lazy loading wouldn't be a good plan, i'd think, if your object is storing data that the entire app needs to run; in other words, i want to make sure this object still has data when it comes back from a background state; it, and many other objects. Cameron's answer suggests that if the viewcontroller's view is still there, then anything it owns is still around too. i could write an exhaustive method to test all of these objects for persistance between app states but that seem potentially overkill if not necessary.

Comment: Cameron is correct - if the view controller is still around, so are any retained properties. If you need persistence without your VC, then you should take a look at Core Data or `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: if the viewcontroller is *not* around, then I presume that the app will call viewDidLoad upon launch, or that this means the application terminated (in the case of a single view controller app). reasonable assumption? thanks for the advice.

Comment: @andrewx let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2827/discussion-between-adamrothman-and-andrewx)